# spring accept entity in controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Typically the spring controller method has such view:

```
@RequestMapping("/url")
public String getUrl([params]){
  // do some stuff..
}
```

As params spring can accept `get/post/delete` .. params from request or some standart params like `model`, `locale` etc.

My question is next: can spring accept my parametr when method is invoked. like:

```
@RequestMapping("/profile")
public String getUserProfile(UserEntity user, [params ..]){
  // do some stuff..
}
```

Here `UserEntity user` is NOT a request body, but the entity from my DB.
Scenario is next: before executing method `getUserProfile`, spring execute some other method, that somehow get user from DB and pass it as method param.
Is there some way to repeat this scenario in real life?

Comment: Have you read [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-methods)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible if you use Spring Data. See the documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/reference/html/#core.web

Basically, what you have to do, is to add the id as parameter, and Spring Data will then use that ID to get the entity from the database and pass it to the method:

```
@RequestMapping("/{id}")
public String showUserForm(@PathVariable("id") User user) {}
```

To enable that feature, you have to put the annotation `@EnableSpringDataWebSupport` onto a `@Configuration` class

Answer (score 0):

Check [here](http://www.journaldev.com/2676/spring-mvc-interceptors-example-handlerinterceptor-and-handlerinterceptoradapter).

We can use MVC interceptors. You need to modify the Interceptor implementation. Check the request URL pattern, if it matches then call a method that returns the UserProfile object. Hope this helps.